# How do I create nested lists in Reminders?

Tags: macos, ios, reminders

I want to use Reminders.app but I also want a little more structure through nested lists. How do I created nested lists with Reminders.app on iOS or OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way but it only works on iOS 9. Simply ask Siri:

> Remind me about this to X list.

While looking at reminders list Y and then list Y will be "nested" inside list X. I say "nested" because list Y will still be accessible from main view and not just list X.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no support for nested lists in Reminders.
I would recommend Todoist if you're looking for nested lists, it does a great job and integrates into OS X and iOS well. There are plenty of other aps that do this too like wunderlist and trello